# Gcloud SQL - Error creating POSTGRES 11 DB

Tags: sql, gcloud

When I try create a POSTGRES 11 db, I have the error below:

gcloud beta  sql instances create db-testing --database-version="POSTGRES_11" --storage-size="10GB" --storage-auto-increase --storage-type="SSD" --region="us-central1"
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) argument --database-version: Invalid choice: 'POSTGRES_11'.

Valid choices are [MYSQL_5_5, MYSQL_5_6, MYSQL_5_7, POSTGRES_9_6].

Comment: Is there something about that error message that you don't understand?  It seems really clear to me.

Comment: Apparently Postgresql 11 isn't supported by gcloud. Try choosing POSTGRES_9_6.

Comment: The documentation says:--database-version=DATABASE_VERSION
The database engine type and version. If left unspecified, the API defaults will be used. DATABASE_VERSION must be one of: MYSQL_5_6, MYSQL_5_7, MYSQL_8_0, POSTGRES_9_6, POSTGRES_10, POSTGRES_11, POSTGRES_12, POSTGRES_13, SQLSERVER_2017_EXPRESS, SQLSERVER_2017_WEB, SQLSERVER_2017_STANDARD, SQLSERVER_2017_ENTERPRISE

Comment: Hello,
So I tried to replicate the same behavior and with the same command, and I think that it would be good to try these two solutions:
1) update your SDK with the command:

gcloud components update

2) also for me the command worked if I added a tier to the command:

gcloud beta sql instances create db-testing --database-version="POSTGRES_11" --storage-size="10GB" --storage-auto-increase --storage-type="SSD" --
region="us-central1" --tier=db-f1-micro

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gcloud sql instances create YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME \
  --database-version=POSTGRES_14 \
  --cpu 2 \
  --memory 4096MB \
  --region=us-central1
```

At region set your preferred location
It worked for me
 Also you can add disk and other commands as posted at your question.